# Style a select and options elements with multiple columns

Tags: css, select, drop-down-menu

I'm using Google Translate selects as a reference.

When you click to choose the languages, the options show with multiple columns.

http://translate.google.com/

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That's not a real SELECT element. Think of it as a popin triggered by clicking on a DIV. Look at it in Firebug to see how they do it.

Edited to show the OP that, no, it's really *not* a SELECT element. This is the markup of the first "SELECT" on the page. Do you see any SELECT element in there? I sure don't.

```
<div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button" title="Detect language" style="-webkit-user-select: none; " tabindex="0">
  <div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-outer-box">
    <div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-inner-box">
      <div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-caption" style="overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: hidden; ">
        Detect language
      </div>
      <div class="goog-inline-block goog-menu-button-dropdown">
        ▼
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Guinivincius: Where did you see the code? My edit above is copied directly from their site.

Comment: By the chrome element inspector I saw the same as you.

So, I'll try the div stuff.

Thanks